# Simple Modrewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, get

i want to redirect only this url 
http://domain.com/?eID=dd_googlesitemap

to
http://domain.com/test.html

my rule is

```
RewriteRule http://domain.com/?eID=dd_googlesitemap http://domain.com/test.html [R=301,L]
```

but it doesnt work. I dont get it. Any ideas whats wrong?

. . .  . . .  . . .  . . .  . . .  . . .  . . .  . . .  . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're getting is that query strings and domains aren't matched by a RewriteRule. Instead you would need to specify these as conditions prior to the rule, using `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^eID=dd_googlesitemap$
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain.com/test.html? [R=301,L]
```

If you don't specify any `[flags]` on the RewriteCond's, then they are AND'd, so here the domain part of the requested URL (the HTTP_HOST) *must* be "domain.com"... "www.domain.com" will not be matched.  Also, if any other options are exist in the query string, it won't match.

Finally, we rewrite a completely empty request (no additional paths, etc), to the new URL. Adding `?` to the end of the URL stops the query string being added.